# Android multiplayer via bluetooth

Tags: android, game-design, multiplayer

How do I transfer game commands between 2 android devices via bluetooth first of all is possible to do this??If possible then someone please help in doing so.Thank u

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely possible. You should look at the Android developer documentation for bluetooth (Ocelot has posted the link).

At the minimum you will have to do this -

1. Discover the devices
2. Pairing and connecting devices
3. One of the device needs to become server. It will open a socket and listen for connection.
4. Other device(s) need to become client. They will try to connect to server.
5. Once a connection is established, client and server can exchange strings of message. These strings can be your game commands.

From my own experience, I would say pay good attention to architecture design for exchanging commands. As it may soon become messy.

Comment: oh thank you Vinayak . Is the game engine necessary for that or can i do it with native api?

Comment: @srinivas: I am not aware of a game engine that provides bluetooth API, so you will have to go with native API probably, whether you use game engine or not.